# Child overlapping parent borders/whitespace between parent and child on different zoom levels

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser, microsoft-edge

Here's the fiddle for my query — https://jsfiddle.net/a0notdj9/1/

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.c {
  display: flex;
  border: 3px solid black;
  align-items: center;
  height: 3rem;
}

.a {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.b {
  align-self: stretch;
}

.b label {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

input {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="c">
  <div class="a">Text goes here</div>
  <div class="b">
    <label>Option</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm on Windows 10 and if I set the zoom level to 80% on Chrome, I'm having whitespace appear between parent and children divs even though there's no padding. It's the same for Edge as well at 80%. You can see the screenshots below:

Edge:

[image: Edge]

Chrome:

[image]

Firefox seems to handle alright in all the zoom levels I tried:

[image]

Similarly, the children of the container div overlap the parent border at certain zoom levels. A crop of the Chrome viewport at 150% zoom is given below where you can notice the slight overlap of the child over the bottom border of the parent. This is quite significant at times:

[image]

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if this is like a bug and it's quite annoying as well. I want to know if there's a way to fix this and make it work the same across browsers.

Comment: I think Chrome actually changed something recently, no longer rounding border widths to a whole number of device pixels. I'm not sure if that's relevant or where to look for more information about it. Possibly https://crbug.com/227192